# Reducing PostgreSQL memory consumption

Tags: memory, postgresql

PostgreSQL chews up 4 GB on 500 concurrent connections? I need to get it below 2 GB, or i have to get a more expensive server :(

Tried:

```
temp_buffers = 800kB
work_mem = 1MB
max_stack_depth = 1MB
```

Comment: There are still *shared_buffers* that should be adjusted. As a starting point check tools like pgtune to get desired config (this one is written by my) https://github.com/kofemann/pgtune

Comment: shared_buffers is 128MB, but like memcached, they should not be allocated per connection? I added more ram (6 GB) to get rid of the unexpected restarts with recovery.

Comment: guess the server needs something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool

Comment: we will have to wait for a student, who want's to get a phd for implementing thread pool in postgres (;